# Typescript conflict between "module/index.d.ts" and "@types/module/index.d.ts"

Tags: typescript, handsontable, typescript-typings, es6-modules

I have a 3rd party module ("handsontable"), which has outdated definition in module folder ("/node_modules/handsontable/handsontable.d.ts"), but proper "index.d.ts" in /node_modules/@types folder.
So the structure is the following:

```
/node_modules
  /@types
    /handsontable
       /index.d.ts (LATEST)
  /handsontable
    /handsontable.d.ts (OUTDATED)
/src/app.ts
```

I am using es6 modules and I don't want to expose handsontable to global, so when I write in app.ts:

```
import ht from 'handsontable'

let options: ht.Options
```

It shows me error, because `ht.Options` does not exist in `/node_modules/handsontable/handsontable.d.ts`, while it only exists in `/node_modules/@types/handsontable/index.d.ts`

Is there anyway to force typescript to load type information from `/node_modules/@type/module` during `import m from "module"`?

Here is my **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules","build","dist", "typings","types"
    ],

    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],

    "typeAcquisition": {
        "enable": true
        // "exclude": [ //tried that too
        //     "handsontable"
        // ]
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "node_modules",
        "paths": {
            "src/*":["../src/*"],
            "app/*":["../src/*"],
            "*":["../src/*", "./node_modules"]
        },
        "target": "es2016",
        //"module": "es6", //es6 is not compatible with webpack.config.ts
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "./build",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es6"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Typescript version**: 2.4.2

Comment: what do you have in your `tsconfig` file?

Comment: just updated the question with the info

Comment: Firstly you need to remove types from the excluded files. Next you need to add the type of handsontable and lastly you need to exclude the problamatic type.

Comment: can you provide a small code sample? I tried what you suggested it didn't work, but I might have messed up the path relativity or something

Comment: I tried all combinations and I so far I see "node_modules/{module}/{module}.d.ts" always takes priority over "node_modules/@types/{module}/index.d.ts" :-(

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment `"node_modules/{module}/{module}.d.ts"` always takes priority over `"node_modules/@types/{module}/index.d.ts"`

So the best workaround I could find so far is to map the **tsconfig.json/compilationOptions/paths**:

```
{
   compilationOptions:{
      baseUrl:"node_modules",
      paths:{
         "handsontable":["@types/handsontable"]
      }
   }    
}
```

What helped me to find it, is the flag **tsc --traceResolution**

Comment: it's  tsc --traceResolution not  tsc --traceResolutions